# How to disable System.setOut and setErr at runtime/startup?

Tags: java, logging, io, outputstream

How to prevent other classes changing the System.out? I would like to set the System.out PrintStream in App.main and make it a final so it can't be changed anymore form the other parts of the App. Is it possible? Any hacky way would do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quick look at the code shows the SecurityManager can be used to prevent changes. ;)

```
public static void setErr(PrintStream err) {
    checkIO();
    setErr0(err);
}

private static void checkIO() {
    SecurityManager sm = getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        sm.checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("setIO"));
    }
}
```

You can use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() to identify the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using your custom security manager. Implement your security manager that will throw AccessControlException if non autorized class calls it with parameter "setIO", i.e. override  `checkPermission();` method. Use `new Throwable().getStackTrace()` to identify caller.